# How to add a labeled mark on your plot in xy-plane by using (tikzpicture)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need a picture like

[image: The graph]

Here is a try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-stealth,  thick](0,0)--(4,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[-stealth, thick](2,-2)--(2,2) node[left]{$y$};

\draw (2,0) circle (1.2cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably need to read the manual, the first chapter is excellent for you. Consider how you placed `x` and `y`. In exactly the same way can you place `a` and `b`, depending on how you wish to do it. Welcome to TeX.SE! :)

Comment: Something like `\draw [fill=gray] (2.5,0.5) circle (2pt) node [above left] {$a$};` should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.9,-3.9)(4.4,4.4)
  \psaxes[labels = none, ticks = none]{->}(0,0)(-3.9,-3.9)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \pscircle(0,0){3}
  \pnodes(1.8,1.2){A}(3.3,3.3){B}
  \psdots(A)(B)
  \uput[135](A){a}
  \uput[135](B){b}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a `tikz` solution to a `tikz` question. You can draw `node`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-stealth,  thick](0,0)--(4,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[-stealth, thick](2,-2)--(2,2) node[left]{$y$};

\draw (2,0) circle (1.2cm);

\node[circle,fill,label={120:a},inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=-2pt] at (2.8,0.5) {};
\node[circle,fill,label={120:b},inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=-2pt] at (3.2,1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With PGFPlots:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits=0.2,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$
]
\addplot [thick, smooth, domain=0:360, data cs=polar] (x,1);
\addplot [only marks, black, mark=*, nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic] table [meta=label] {
x   y   label
0.5 0.4 a
0.8 1   b
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with PSTricks just for fun! It might be simpler than the existing one.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4.5,4.5)
  \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \pscircle{3}
  \pstGeonode[PosAngle=120](2,1){a}(3.5,3.5){b}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]